# How to get the domain and range for the straight and curved line together?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, integral-domain

[image]

I was trying to find the domain and range of the graph . I have found  the domain:  [-6,4]  and the range is [-5,1].  But this doesn't match with the answer. Is it a wrong way to consider the range of the domain and range from the graph directly?

Comment: so the domain is right?

Comment: Yes your domain is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints**:

Note that the graph is discontinuous at $x=-4$ and that *there does not exist $x $ for which $y \in (0,-1] $*.

$$\implies \text { Range } = \,\,? $$ $$\implies \text { Domain } = \,\,? $$

Hope you can take it from here.

Comment: So the range is $(−5,−1)U [0,1)$ and the domain is [-6,4] ?

Comment: @SabbirHasan Yes, you are right.